# Django - ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Confirm email'

Tags: python, django, validation

I keep getting this error and for the life of me I can't find the source of the problem.

Traceback:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = middleware_method(request)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py in process_request
                if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in is_valid_path
            resolve(path, urlconf)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve
        return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in resolve
                for pattern in self.url_patterns:

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in url_patterns
            patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in urlconf_module
                self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module
            __import__(name)

/Users/user/Desktop/user/urls.py in <module>
    import contacts.views

/Users/user/Desktop/contacts/views.py in <module>
    import forms

/User/Desktop/contacts/forms.py in <module>
    class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

/Users/Desktop/contacts/forms.py in ContactForm
            required=True,
```

I'm following along the effective django tutorials and at this [page](http://effectivedjango.com/tutorial/forms.html), but i can't get past the email validation section. I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here.

Forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

from contacts.models import Contact

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    confirm_email = forms.EmailField(
        "Confirm email",
        required=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Contact

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):# Constructor mutates kwarg.

        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            email = kwargs['instance'].email# Instance is the name of what's being edited
            kwargs.setdefault('initial', {})['confirm_email'] = email

        return super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        if (self.cleaned_data.get('email') !=
            self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_email')):

                raise ValidationError(
                    "Email address must match."
                )

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Models:

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
email = models.EmailField()

def __str__(self):
    return ' '.join([
    self.first_name,
    self.last_name,
    ])

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('contacts-view', kwargs={'pk': self.id})#Returns address of a contact.
```

Comment: Please post the traceback for your error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `confirm_email` to using keyword arguments:

```
confirm_email = forms.EmailField(label="Confirm email", required=True)
```

Because when you define it as:

```
confirm_email = forms.EmailField("Confirm email", required=True)
```

The constructor of `forms.EmailField` got `Confirm email` as `max_length`:

```
    def __init__(self, max_length=None, min_length=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.max_length, self.min_length = max_length, min_length
        super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: That did it! I can't believe it was so simple. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Thanks - I got the same error here while following the tutorial on EffectiveDjango (where the topic starter's code is coming from as well). This apparently is due to the Django version mismatch: 1.5.1 (author's) and 1.6 (most recent at this time of writing). See https://github.com/nyergler/effective-django-tutorial/issues/5.

Comment: This error is quite frequent in Django when you happen to do, Model.objects.get(pk='') so make sure you don't pass any string in pk lookup.